# Compose function in Paul Graham's On Lisp ( and also in Ansi Common Lisp)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In Paul Graham book, On Lisp, page 66, we have this function :

```
(defun compose (&rest fns)
  (if fns
      (let ((fn1 (car (last fns)))
            (fns (butlast fns)))
        #'(lambda (&rest args)
            (reduce #'funcall fns
                    :from-end t
                    :initial-value (apply fn1 args))))
      #'identity))
```

[this function is written like this, in Paul Graham book, Ansi Common Lisp, page 110] :

```
(defun compose (&rest fns)
  (destructuring-bind (fn1 . rest) (reverse fns)
     (lambda (&rest args)
       (reduce #'(lambda (v f) (funcall f v))
               rest
               :initial-value (apply fn1 args)))))
```

which gives for example :

```
CL-USER> (funcall (compose #'1+ #'find-if) #'oddp '(2 3 4))
4
```

I know that questions have already been asked regarding this function, and that many answers have 
already been provided :
[(compose) in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424954/compose-in-common-lisp)
[Compose example in Paul Graham's ANSI Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928106/compose-example-in-paul-grahams-ansi-common-lisp)

But there is always one thing that is not clear to me.
I know that :

```
fn1 <# <FUNCTION FIND-IF>
fns <(# <FUNCTION 1+>)>  
args <(#<FUNCTION ODDP> (2 3 4))>
```

However, I do not understand how the instruction works:

```
(apply fn1 args)
```

I thought that by testing individually, replacing `fn1` with `#'find-if`, and `args` with `(#'oddp (2 3 4))`:

```
(apply #'find-if #'oddp '(2 3 4))  
or
(apply #'find-if (#'oddp (2 3 4)))
```

it would work, but it doesn't:

```
CL-USER> (apply #'find-if #'oddp '(2 3 4))
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNKNOWN-KEYWORD-ARGUMENT {10036BBD03}>.

CL-USER> (apply #'find-if (#'oddp (2 3 4)))
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-INT:COMPILED-PROGRAM-ERROR {1003DE6413}>.

CL-USER> (apply #'find-if '(#'oddp (2 3 4)))
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: (OR FUNCTION SYMBOL) datum: #'ODDP>.
```

Could someone explain to me how this instruction works?
Thank you in advance for your indulgence and your responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you want to create a list of three items:  a function object and two numbers. Use

```
(list #'+ 1 2)
```

Don't use:

```
(#'+ 1 2)     ; that's not valid Common Lisp code. The
              ;  first element of a Lisp form can't be a function object.
              ;  It's violating the basic evaluation rules
              ;  of Common Lisp.

'(#'+ 1 2)    ; This does not evaluate the list. Quoting makes it
              ;  a constant literal list. The elements of the list
              ;  won't be evaluated.
              ; Thus the first item is not a function object,
              ; but the list (function +)
```

Definition:

*Lisp form*: valid code meant to be evaluated